# xsl: xml to csv conversion - search list for value, otherwise output empty field

Tags: xslt, date, csv, foreach

I have an xml structure like:

```
   <foos>
      <foo>
        <foo_type>1</foo_type>
        <foo_date>2011_1_1</foo_date>
      </foo>
      <foo>
        <foo_type>1</foo_type>
        <foo_date>2012_1_1</foo_date>
      </foo>
      <foo>
        <foo_type>2</foo_type>
        <foo_date>2011_1_1</foo_date>
      </foo>
    </foos>
```

What I need to do is produce one value from this, where foo_type==1 and the date is latest date.  Previously I have used a sort descending for a list of dates.  If there is no foo of foo_type==1 it should produce an empty field.  (Fields are surrounded with quotes, comma is the delimiter.)

I was envisioning doing this by building a list of all foos of type 1.  I'm not sure how to do that in xsl. something like this perhaps:

```
        <xsl:variable name="fooList">
            <xsl:for-each select="foos/foo">
                <xsl:if test="contains(foo_type, '1')">
                    <xsl:value-of select="concat($fooList, ', ', foo_date)"/>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:variable>
```

then i would parse the comma delimited list and sort to determine the latest date:

```
       <xsl:variable name="latestFooDate">
            <xsl:sort select="split(fooList)" order="descending" />
       </xsl:variable>
```

and finally call the template to format the result:

```
        <xsl:call-template name="dateFormat">
            <xsl:with-param name="date" select="latestFooDate" />
        </xsl:call-template>
```

Keep in mind this is pseudo code because I dont know how to do this.  Now if someone can help turn my pseudo into the real thing.

Comment: This should be straight-forward, but I am confused as to where the CSV requirement comes into it. If you only want to produce one value, then you won't need to worry about comma delimters. It will just be a single field. Perhaps showing your expected output would help? Thanks!

Comment: Hello Tim, thanks for the reply.  This is just one of many fields in the csv document to be created.

Comment: Expected output would be: "2012_1_1",  altho technically i need to call another dateFormat template I created to format the date like 2012_JAN_1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need to create a comma-delimited list before getting the first date. This seems like a bit of extra effort. You could sort your **foo** elements in your **xsl:for-each** statement, and then just get the first one (i.e. the one with **position() = 1**)

Try this template for matching a **foos** element

```
   <xsl:template match="foos">
      <xsl:for-each select="foo[foo_type='1']"> 
         <xsl:sort select="foo_date" />
         <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
            <xsl:value-of select="foo_date" />
         </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each> 
   </xsl:template>
```

This loops over all **foo** elements with a **foo_type** of 1, but then only performs any processing on the first one.

When you use this template to match your given input XML, the output should then be

```
2011_1_1
```

You can then go ahead and perform extra date formatting on this as required.